# Exported functions in a dynamic library in C++

Tags: c++

In a C++ dynamic library (windows), usually we use `__declspec(dllexport)` to denote the class or function we want to export so that the user of the library can invoke this class or function. So my question is should we use this keyword very carefully when we design the dynamic library. What's the effect if we export too many functions in a dynamic library?

Answer (score 2):

Usually exported functions are part of the library public interface, and the author guarantees that library users may rely on these methods in next (few) releases of the library.